# Android Emulator on OS X with Retina Display

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to use Android Emulator on Macbook Pro with retina display (and an external 4K display with 2x pixel scaling). I've tried all the possible settings in Android AVD Manager, but emulator always shows a blurry non-retina image. It seems that it treats the display like if it is 1920x1080 instead of 4K thus 1:1 pixel mapping actually happens to be 1px on device = 4px on the display.

Is there any way to make it work well?

Thank you

(I'm using OS X El Capitan and Android Studio 1.4.1)

Comment: I think it's the AVD emulators not support on host machine retina? Even I changed the 'Scale' to '4dp on device = 1px on screen' the '1px on screen' always is actual 4pixel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering by myself — seems that it just works now with the Android Studio 2.0.